# API response to CSV file

Tags: python

I want to pass this API response to a simple CSV file:

```
[[1467167400,576.01,576.01,576.01,576.01,0.72],
[1467166200,579.03,579.03,579.03,579.03,0.02],
[1467165900,580,580,580,580,1.6505],
[1467165600,580,580.53,580.53,580.01,0.5467],
[1467165000,584,584.63,584.63,584,10.438751879999998],
[1467164700,585,586.48,586.48,585,1.0923],
[1467164100,585,587.72,587.3,587.72,2.61],
[1467163800,587.66,587.66,587.66,587.66,0.04],
[1467163200,588.02,588.02,588.02,588.02,0.2],
[1467162600,587.84,587.84,587.84,587.84,0.16],
[1467162000,588.1,588.26,588.26,588.1,0.12000000000000001]]
```

And I want a CSV file like this:

```
2017-05-28 14:00:00 UTC,1922.51735897436,1961.0,1879.01
2017-05-28 15:00:00 UTC,1869.88877403846,1906.28,1827.14
2017-05-28 16:00:00 UTC,1860.06581132075,1897.83,1833.81
2017-05-28 17:00:00 UTC,1885.3259798995,1906.99,1859.01
2017-05-28 18:00:00 UTC,1881.34923469388,1907.32,1859.01
2017-05-28 19:00:00 UTC,1887.00946153846,1905.82,1867.04
2017-05-28 20:00:00 UTC,1854.78940860215,1877.0,1840.01
2017-05-28 21:00:00 UTC,1870.5975,1886.99,1845.36
2017-05-28 22:00:00 UTC,1899.98381756757,1921.44,1875.97
2017-05-28 23:00:00 UTC,1923.40009009009,1940.03,1906.86
```

How can I easily do this? And if I want to change the order of the rows, like low price change to high price and vice versa?

Comment: i want to also change the unix to iso.. there is any module that help in this?

Comment: What did you try so far, and why didn't that work? It's not clear how your input should be mapped to the output, since the data and number of columns are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through the list you have and write to a file/print like so

```
for item in dict:
  comma = ''
  out = ""
  for element in item:
    out.join(comma,element)
    comma = ','
  print(out)
```